# How to display data in Table format in microsoft bot framework

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

Can some one please help me out in displaying the data table format in BOT as below

[image]

Comment: What channel are you using? Not all channels support HTML style message formatting.

Comment: What does channel means? I am using MS bot frame work

Comment: Channel is like - Skype, Slack, MS Teams, WebChat, SfB, SMS, Email, etc.

Comment: I need to implement it in all the channel

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can leverage the [ColumeSet](http://adaptivecards.io/explorer/ColumnSet.html) in [adaptive card](http://adaptivecards.io/) to render a table like card message.

E.G, the following json content will be renderred a table like card message:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "weight": "bolder",
                            "text": "Name"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "separator":true,
                            "text": "Apple"
                        },{
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "separator":true,
                            "text": "Kiwi"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "weight": "bolder",
                            "text": "Tag"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "separator":true,
                            "text": "Fruit"
                        },{
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "separator":true,
                            "text": "Fruit"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "weight": "bolder",
                            "text": "Price"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "separator":true,
                            "text": "2"
                        },{
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "separator":true,
                            "text": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

in WebChat channel, it looks like:

[image]

Comment: any way to do the same thing in MessageCard format because connectors doesn't support Adaptive Card format

Comment: Office 365 connectors only support the legacy **MessageCard** format for cards. They do not support the **Adaptive Card** format. I want to send a message using webhook url and body content as a table format. any way to do it?. when I send adaptive formate it shows blank body content on my MS msg

Comment: Or may I need to use this way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60201303/1138192 which I don't like personally to send table inside the **text**

Comment: @Gary, there's no vertical and horizontal scroll for adaptive cards when using it on MS Teams. Please, how can I add a scroll bar to an adaptive card?