# How to use customized cards with Microsoft Teams webhook

Tags: post, webhooks, microsoft-teams

Adaptive cards receive "bad request 400" error

I'm trying to send a POST request from AWS Lambda running Python 3.7 using the urlopen method

I have a regular card request that is working but an adaptive card will hit the error mentioned above.

Example of working card:

{'@context': 'https://schema.org/extensions', '@type': 'MessageCard', 'themeColor': 'd63333', 'title': 'Red Alert - There is an issue Example alarm name', 'text': '**Example alarm name** has changed from OK to ALARM - Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint (10.0) was greater than or equal to the threshold (1.0).'}

Example of customized card (getting bad request error - 400):

{'@context': 'https://schema.org/extensions', '@type': 'AdaptiveCard', 'padding': 'none', 'body': [{'type': 'Container', 'style': 'emphasis', 'items': [{'type': 'ColumnSet', 'columns': [{'type': 'Column', 'items': [{'type': 'Image', 'horizontalAlignment': 'Right', 'url': 'https://miro.medium.com/max/1000/1*sszpZOih_xJV_lZsDbog-Q.png', 'height': '50px', 'altText': 'MC Logo'}], 'width': 'auto'}]}]}, {'type': 'Container', 'padding': {'top': 'none', 'left': 'default', 'bottom': 'default', 'right': 'default'}, 'items': [{'type': 'Container', 'items': [{'type': 'ColumnSet', 'spacing': 'Large', 'separator': 1, 'columns': [{'type': 'Column', 'verticalContentAlignment': 'center', 'items': [{'type': 'Image', 'horizontalAlignment': 'Center', 'style': 'Person', 'url': 'https://www.sccpre.cat/mypng/detail/57-574129_4-warning-stamp-vector-png-transparent-svg-warning.png', 'width': '60px', 'altText': 'warning logo'}], 'width': '60px'}, {'type': 'Column', 'items': [{'type': 'TextBlock', 'size': 'Medium', 'text': '**Example alarm name** issue description', 'wrap': 1}, {'type': 'TextBlock', 'spacing': 'None', 'text': 'MC ETL Process notifier', 'isSubtle': 1}], 'width': 'stretch'}]}, {'type': 'FactSet', 'facts': [{'title': 'Incident time:', 'value': '06/07/2019 03:10:12 AM CT'}, {'title': 'Component:', 'value': 'AWS Glue - insert funds job'}, {'title': 'Overall nightly done:', 'value': '73%'}]}, {'type': 'TextBlock', 'spacing': 'Small', 'weight': 'Bolder', 'color': 'Accent', 'size': 'Medium', 'text': '[Click to restart](https://expense.localzoho.com/app#/approvals/27262000000098057)'}, {'type': 'TextBlock', 'spacing': 'Small', 'weight': 'Bolder', 'color': 'Accent', 'size': 'Medium', 'text': '[Click to review logs](https://expense.localzoho.com/app#/approvals/27262000000098057)'}]}]}], 'version': '1.0'}

What is wrong with my POST request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, Teams incoming Webhooks does not support Adaptive Cards. You can send only [Message Card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors-using#example-connector-message) in connector messages. We are working on the Adaptive Card support but do not have timeline to share.

Comment: I can't sorry:
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Any update on Adaptive Card format using webhooks because I need a table format and currently not able to send it using Message Card. Though I saw this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60201303/1138192 but I want something like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/48160573/1138192

Comment: Adaptive card is supported now in incoming Webhook. Please try this [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using#send-adaptive-cards-using-an-incoming-webhook) mentioned in documentation

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT Are you able to edit your post as well to reflect the changes of Oct 2020? Your comment can be easily overlooked and might be result in developers missing out on the ability to use AdaptiveCards in Incoming Webhooks